# What is the best non-deep learning hand written digits recognition system?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, sequential-pattern-mining

What would be the best Sequence Mining Algorithm to use for Hand Written digit Recognition system (other then Deep learning)?

Answer (score 1):

One of the best non-deep learning systems for MNIST is  [k-nearest neighbors algorithm (k-NN) with non-linear deformation (P2DHMDM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database#Performance).

Comment: K-NN with non-linear deformation (P2DHMDM) is best in the linked web page.

Comment: You are correct. I have updated my answer.